# await import in React/NextJS/Typescript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm running this code on a node.js development server:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import nextBase64 from 'next-base64';
   
const Load = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { obj } = router.query
  var decoded = nextBase64.decode(obj)

  return <p>Post: {decoded}</p>
}

export default Load
```

When I navigate to the page, which is a base64 encoded string, It tells me:

> Server Error
>
> TypeError: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined
> This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
> Source

```
pages/media/load/[obj].tsx (15:16) @ Load

  13 | const router = useRouter()
  14 | const { obj } = router.query
> 15 | var decoded = nextBase64.decode(obj)
     |              ^
  16 | 
  17 | return <p>Post: {decoded}</p>
  18 | }
```

However, if I remove the `nextBase64.decode(obj)` and print the `obj` it works, printing the encoded string. But here's the kicker. When I revert the change it *also* works and prints the decoded string.

I think the `import nextBase64 from 'next-base64';` statement isn't imported in time for when the function is exported.

What is best practice here, should I do some kind of `await import` (I tried and failed) or should I import inside the function somehow?

Comment: this is the normal behavior of [`router.query`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object) if you're not using `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps`. or you can use `router.isReady` inside of `useEffect`. see this [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-lumiere-b94rw4?file=/pages/media/load/%5Bobj%5D.js:0-483)

Comment: @mocherfaoui Thank you, that helped me solve the issue. Do you want to make that a proper answer so I can green checkbox it or shall I?

Comment: sure! I added the comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the normal behavior of [`router.query`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object) if you're not using `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps`. or you can use `router.isReady` inside of `useEffect`.

see the below codesandbox example

[image: Edit epic-lumiere-b94rw4]